# __construct($foo = NULL) is not working

Tags: php, construct

I have strange problem. This is just constructor method of class, not worth to show other code, anyway, look at this code:

```
Class xy {
    public $x = 10;
    public $y = 10; 

    public function __construct($x = NULL, $y = NULL) {
        if(isset($x) || isset($y)){
            $this->x = $x;      // assign center coords
            $this->y = $y;      // assign center coords
        }
        $this->area = $this->area();
        echo $this->x . " " . $this->y . " " . $this->area;
    }

}
```

Since now, I thought that this code should echo $this->x and $this->y WITHOUT `if(isset($x) || isset($y)){`, if its not passed in on object making with this code: `$newObj = new xy;` But it doesn't. It works only if this line looks like this `$newObj = new xy(10,10)`;

I need help and clarification :)

Comment: Will changing `isset()` to `!is_null()` help?

Comment: `$x === NULL || $this->x = $x;` same for the second argument. Only set if not default. You need to do that per argument.

Comment: @Passerby, `isset` is logically equivalent to `!is_null` (their return values are identical for all inputs).

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t use php for years, but I think it should looks like $newObj = new xy();

Comment: The point is, that I think, it should work without 6th and 9th row in code, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
change $newObj = xy(10,10); to $newObj = new xy(10,10);
```